# Can I change the minSdk from 2.3 to 4 for an existing Google Play Store app with an upgrade

Tags: android

If I have an existing app on the store with minSdk = 2.3.4 and now I change that to 4.1.2, will the store accept the new apk? What will happen to users with 2.3.4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Play Store will accept the new APK.

As long as you keep both APKs uploaded on Play Store, your existing customers will be able to get that version. They will not receive the new version as an update, if their software version is not compatible

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. This means that only users with API level 16 or higher will get updates of your app. User with lower versions will get no updates and cannot install your app.

But it is possible to keep the older version, so that user with lower version can install your old app version.